How do I syntax highlight this comment as if it were Python?
I am currently working on a Python(-like) project which contains code like this:
def func():
    """
    This is a docstring.

    EXAMPLES::

        sage: func()
        1
    """
    return 1

The Python syntax highlighting is working great on the code. In particular, the documentation inside the triple quotes are all highlighted green, as they are marked as the pythonString syntax group. However, I would like to highlight the words after sage:  (just that line) as if it's Python code.
I have gotten something close. Here is my attempt:
vim.cmd.syn('region sageDoctestValue start=/^ *sage: /ms=e+1 end=/$/ containedin=pythonString contained')
vim.cmd.highlight('link sageDoctestValue Define')

Now the syntax highlighting looks like this. However, I want the lines to highlight like Python code (like the first import line), not just as some fixed highlight group. Is that possible?
I'm not using any semantic highlighting plugins, just the plain Python syntax highlighting by Vim.


As for jumping to definitions, you could work around that by using tags or cscope instead of LSP.

I've removed the update with the answer (you can find it in the edit history). Please post an answer with your solution, even if it's only partial!

I have done that :)

" after/syntax/sage.vim

runtime! syntax/python.vim
unlet b:current_syntax
syntax include @Python syntax/python.vim

syn region sageDoctestValue contained
      \ start=/^ *\(sage\|\.\.\.\.\): /ms=e+1 end=/$/
      \ containedin=pythonString contains=@Python

This is pretty good, but e.g. LSP functionality (jump to definition etc.) is not supported, though for understandable reasons (this is purely syntax highlighting). As Friedrich mentioned in the comments, tags or other functionalities can still be used to replace LSP for say jumping to symbols.

